# Want my Bluetooth keyboard on Galaxy Tab10.1 to default to English Android Keyboard (Not to Samsung Japanese Keypad)

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, peripherals

I am using a Galaxy Tab 10.1 and when I connect my iBuffalo Bluetooth Keyboard BSKBB06 it always defaults to the Samsung Japanese Keypad and I have to keep manually changing it to the English Android Keyboard and then to the Null Keyboard.

Is there a way I can get it to default to the English Keyboard and then straight to the Null?  I disconnect and connect multiple times in a day and so always having to change the default keyboard is getting quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system settings under **Language and input methods** and check what keyboard is currently selected. It might be the reason why you're getting a different input method by default.